# Why can't I inject a WebServiceContext into a Jax-WS logical Handler

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws

I have this logical handler for a web service that I need to get access to the servlet's context (via the web service context, I am thinking).

```
package test;

public class NewLogicalHandler implements LogicalHandler<LogicalMessageContext> {

   @Resource
   private WebServiceContext context;
```

Error when I deploy:

```
<Servlet: "test.ws1" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "web".
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.NewLogicalHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

If I inject into the web service proper:

```
@WebService(..stuff...)
@HandlerChain(file = "handler.xml")
public class ws1 {

   @Resource
   private WebServiceContext context;
```

That works fine.

Comment: the class was not found in the classpath so i suggest that you need to make sure it is in the classpath first.

Comment: It is.  Because if I remove the @Resouce, then it deploys fine, and the handler can be invoked.  I'm thinking it may be some order of loading issue?

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` happens when a class is not found under classpath by the class loader so in this case `test.NewLogicalHandler` is not found. This usually happen when you build a war application but the dependency isn't in the war file. Or you are using a class loader that unable to find `test.NewLogicalHandler` in some of your jar file under classparth. I cannot think of any other reason.

Comment: When you removed `@Resource` annotation, it started up fine, maybe, because it doesn't need to construct `WebServiceContext` which depends on  `test.NewLogicalHandler`

Comment: I checked and the class exists in the the war file.

Comment: Never mind.  Can get servlet context from LogicalMessageContext.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Can get servlet context from LogicalMessageContext.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);